# How do I Replace array of conditional values using JSONata

Tags: jsonata

I have a large array of "Application Status" values that need to be replaced based upon conditional statements.

F.ex.

1. If the app status is **"Approved"** or **"Missing in DocuPhase"** or **"On hold - Pending Funding"** or **"Only Missing Owner Clearance"** or **"Pending Payment Processing"** or **"Pending Quality Control Review"** or **"Reviewed"**,  the Portal status = **Under Review**
2. If app status is **"On Hold - Funding Exhausted"**, the Portal status = **Exhausted**
3. If the app status is **"Denial Pending"** or **"Denial PQCR"** or **"Review Finalized"**, the Portal status = **Denied**
4. If the app status is **"Payment Import"** or **"Payment Sent"**, the Portal status = Disbursed
5. Else (any other app status) = **Requested**

I was trying something like this:

```
$replace(result.fields[label = "R.Application Status"].values.value.text, ["Approved", "Missing in DocuPhase", "On hold - Pending Funding", "Only Missing Owner Clearance", "Pending Payment Processing", "Pending Quality Control Review", "Reviewed"], "Under Review")
```

However, this does not work and I want to get away from doing something ugly like this:

```
$replace($replace($replace($replace($replace($replace($replace($replace(result.fields[label = "R.Application Status"].values.value.text, "Approved", "Under Review"), "Missing in DocuPhase", "Under Review"), "On hold - Pending Funding", "Under Review"), "Only Missing Owner Clearance", "Under Review"), "Pending Payment Processing", "Under Review"), "Pending Quality Control Review", "Under Review"), "Reviewed", "Under Review")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to get a list of statuses parsed from the original object structure with certain statuses replaced, you can do it with a regular expression passed down to the `$replace` function like this: https://stedi.link/RMFB0yj

Alternatively, you can achieve the same if you use a ternary expression within a map operator: https://stedi.link/bg96HrE

If you need to preserve the original structure and only want certain statuses to be replaced, then I would do it like that: https://stedi.link/wB5f9tu